# Subjunctive or indicative after "ce n'est pas clair si"

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif

The phrase "Ce n'est pas clair que ...", which demonstrates doubt, requires the subjunctive.

> Ce n'est pas clair **que** la fête ce soir ait lieu chez Pierre.

What about "Ce n'est pas clair si ..." if there are two (or more) options? Is this idiomatic in French? If so, does it require the subjunctive or the indicative?

> Ce n'est pas clair **si** la fête (ait / va avoir) lieu chez Pierre ou chez Marie.

What if there is only one option?

> Ce n'est pas clair **si** la fête (ait / va avoir) lieu chez Pierre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, *pas clair que* is present in [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/clair), but not *pas clair si* (as far as I can tell - please correct me if I missed it). In terms of frequency of use in writing, it looks like *pas clair si* is becoming more and more common. Interestingly, *pas clair que* was overwhelmingly dominant in the 19th century, but *pas clair si* is becoming more and more used in the second half of the 20th century. Overall *pas clair que* is still about twice as frequent as *pas clair si* today. But still not mentioned in CNRTL as far as I could tell (?)

Back to your sentences, the following sounds ok to me:

> ***Il***/Ce n'est pas clair si la fête **va avoir** lieu chez Pierre ou chez Marie.

and

> ***Il***/Ce n'est pas clair si la fête **va avoir** lieu chez Pierre (ou non).

I don't think the number of options plays any role here, but *ait* IMHO doesn't work at all. In the second example I put *(ou non)* in parentheses to indicate that it is optional.

Maybe the following would be even more natural, although not strictly equivalent (this *il n'est pas clair* is a bit awkward):

> Je ne sais pas si la fête va avoir lieu chez Pierre (ou non).

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's relevant to compare things that don't have the same place in a sentence. For example, you can say "c'est clair que ..." (but *clair si* make sense only with "***c'est pas clair si*** *c'est A ou B*". "*Clair que*" also appears in "*A est plus clair que B*", or "C'est plus clair que ...*", two situations where you can't use "*clair si*". It's used in a very specific situation, it's not fair to compare it to "*clair que*".

Comment: Just look at [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=c'est+clair%2Cc'est+pas+clair%2C+ce+n'est+pas+clair&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cc'est) and tell me yours isn't biased. Oh and "*Je ne sais pas si...*" and "*C'est pas clair si...*" are ***not*** equivalent.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat - I am not going to tell you mine isn't biased. I am going to tell you that you are right, that you make a good point, and that I am updating my answer - the new graph shows that _pas clair si_ is becoming more common. :-)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat - Also, I know that "c'est pas clair si" and "je ne sais pas si" are not strictly equivalent, but "je ne sais pas si" sounds better and quite probable in spoken language to me. Actually, in spoken language we might say something like: _c'est pas si clair si c'est chez Pierre ou pas_.