# Qu’est-ce que « Il n’est pas clair que » veut dire en anglais?

Tags: traduction, subjonctif, indicatif

Ce genre de phrase me pose souvent des problèmes - en anglais "It is not evident that he likes cake" indique le plupart de temps que ce n'est pas clair (i.e. ce n'est pas montré d'une façon ouverte) mais il aime quand-même les gateaux - alors, c'est une réalité (indicatif). Mais, en français il faut le subjonctif - alors, le sens de la phrase est-il plutôt "It's not evident if / whether"? Peut-on dire "Il n'est pas clair si" (if) ou "Il n'est pas clair qu'elle préfère le gateau ou le chocolat" (whether)?

Merci d'avance!

Answer (score 1):

L'expression étant rare, elle peut sonner faux mais on rencontre suffisamment d'occurrences de ***il n'est pas clair si*** pour ne pas la rejeter.

Rien n'interdit donc écrire:

> **Il n'est pas clair si elle préfère les gâteaux ou le chocolat.**

Exemple d'utilisation :

> *Le texte dit en substance qu'«ils» ont des ressources importantes, mais **il n'est pas clair si** ce pronom renvoie aux deux camps ou aux seuls Athéniens.*
>
> Olivier Cosma, *Les racines littéraires de l'Europe*,  2010.

et:

> *b. **Il n'est pas clair si** Jean partira en Europe.
>
> c. Il n'est pas clair quand/où Jean partira.*
>
> Catherine Léger, *La complémentation de type phrastique des adjectifs en français*, p 134, 2006.

Le mode qui suit « si » est l'indicatif.

Bien sûr, on peut trouver d'autres formes si la précédente déplaît, par exemple :

> On ne sait pas si elle préfère les gâteaux ou le chocolat.
> On ne devine pas si...
> Sa préférence pour les gâteaux ou le chocolat n'est pas connue.
> etc.

Voir aussi: [Subjunctive or indicative after "ce n'est pas clair si"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24416/subjunctive-or-indicative-after-ce-nest-pas-clair-si)

Comment: Dans b et c de Léger, ce qui suit _clair_ est-il un complément de type phrastique (de l'adjectif) ?

Comment: @AmandeAdorable *Clair* est défini comme adjectif propositionnel discursif et *si jean partira en Europe* comme complétive interrogative indirecte. Je pense qu'il s'agit bien d'un complément de type phrastique mais le *si* pose peut-être problème. J'avoue ne pas avoir lu les 429 pages de la thèse...

Answer (score 0):

In English, "ce n'est pas clair" means "this is not clear".
Simple as that.
"pas clair" means we do not know for sure.
This is why you get the subjonctive later.
Nothing is guaranteed regarding the statement.

Example. There is a race and two cars arrived, it would seem, at the same time at the arrival. Jean is saying one of the drivers won. But Delphine knows better.
Jean: "Je crois que Patrick a gagnè !"
Delphine, having no clue: "Ce n'est pas clair qu'il ait gagné. Il est arrivé en même temps".

Sounds a bit artificial yet this is correct. Delphine is making a point that nothing is certain for now (they may need to see pictures of the arrival line).

(And no, you cannot use "si" after this phrase)